# python regexp not match sequence

Tags: python, regex

I need to wrap some MathJax string with HTML tag. I wonder how to exclude `\)` from search string not to match full sting. With single char it's easy e.g `[^)]` but what to do when I need to do the same with e.g. two chars one after another `\)` ?

```
search_str = "\(\ce{\sigma_{s}^{b}(H2O)}\) bla bla \(\ce{\sigma_{s}^{b}(H2O)}\)"
out = re.sub(r'(\\\([^\\\)]+\\\))', '<span>\1</span>', search_str)
```

Comment: Lazy matching (`.+?`) should be sufficient, a [tempred greedy token](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3836111) might be better. Both won't help with nested parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to match any text but `\)` 2-char substring, 2-char *sequence* of characters, with `[^\\\)]+`, which is wrong, because `[^...]` is a [negated cahracter class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that can match a *single* character falling into a specific range or set of chars defined in the class. It can never match char combinations, `*` or `+` quantifiers just repeat a single char matching.

What you think of is called a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed), `(?:(?!\\\)).)*` or `(?:(?!\\\)).)*?`.

However, the [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) is not the best practice in this case. See the rexegg.com note on when **not** to use TGT:

> For the task at hand, this technique presents no advantage over the lazy dot-star `.*?{END}`. Although their logic differs, at each step, before matching a character, both techniques force the engine to look if what follows is `{END}`.
>
> The comparative performance of these two versions will depend on your engine's internal optimizations. The [pcretest](http://www.rexegg.com/pcregrep-pcretest.html) utility indicates that PCRE requires far fewer steps for the lazy-dot-star version. On my laptop, when running both expressions a million times against the string `{START} Mary {END}`, pcretest needs 400 milliseconds per 10,000 runs for the lazy version and 800 milliseconds for the tempered version.
>
> Therefore, if the string that tempers the dot is a delimiter that we intend to match eventually (as with `{END}` in our example), this technique adds nothing to the lazy dot-star, which is better optimized for this job.

Your strings seem to be well-formed and rather short, use a mere *lazy dot matching pattern*, that is, `\\\(.*?\\\)` regex.

Besides, you need to use `r` prefix, a raw string literal, in the replacement pattern definition, or `\1` will be parsed as a hex char (`\x01`, *start of header*).

```
import re
search_str = r"\(\ce{\sigma_{s}^{b}(H2O)}\) bla bla \(\ce{\sigma_{s}^{b}(H2O)}\)"
print(search_str)
out = re.sub(r'(\\\(.*?\\\))', r'<span>\1</span>', search_str)
print(out)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fS2VqR)

Answer (score 0):

I think that `[^\\][^)]` should do the trick, or.  nearly so. That will match any two characters as long as the first isn't a slash, and the second isn't a closing paren. You could experiment with some grouping, too, if that's not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Sebastian's recommendation I used Tempered Greedy Token:

```
(\\\((?:(?!\\\)).)*\\\)
```

simply awesome :-)